# Fill missing value with mean of another variable based on categories in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na, imputation

I want to replace NA values in `val2` in each row with the mean of `val` corresponding to that `ID` column. Any easy (tidyverse) way to do this?

**Also, I want to know how to replace it by `mean(na.rm=TRUE)` of `val2` values itself by categories** (For ex: for row 6 & 9 val2 will be replace by 4, `mean(na.rm=TRUE)` of `val2` (for `ID==c`))

For the dataframe in this image :

[image: Image link]

R code:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                 val=c(seq(1:9)), val2=c(1,2,4,NA,5,NA,7,NA,NA))
```

Comment: This is called **"target mean imputation"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself, incase any answer suggestions which is better than this then please share

```
df %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(val2 = ifelse(is.na (val2), mean(val), val2))
```

For Point

```
df %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
mutate(val2 = ifelse(is.na(val2), mean(val2,na.rm=TRUE), val2))
```

Comment: @NelsonGon I have mentioned the R dataframe code in the question, not sure what else is required ?